# Design suggestions for executing tasks that will be triggered based on configuration

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

In my web application, there is a web page displaying certain fields and its value. The values can be edited by the users. Once the values are edited, they are persisted into the database. Now comes the problem where i need suggestions. Once the values are updated into DB, i need to run few modules which are time consuming. So this time consuming part may or may not be done instantaneously depending on the configuration. The options in the configuration can be Instantaneous, Hourly, Daily, Weekly or Monthly. So if it instantaneous i have to run the modules or else i should trigger the task at the specified time based on the configuration.

Is job scheduler, a good way of solving this problem? Heard about Quartz.NET. Are there any .NET libraries available to achieve this. Pls provide suggesions.

Comment: I may be old-fashioned, but overall I wouldn't recommend hosting long-running tasks inside of a web application. If you have enough permissions on your server, I suggest you create a service that will pool the database to fetch new tasks, then schedule and execute them using a library like Quartz.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It much recommended to store these jobs in a queue and create another asynchronize service  to execute the queue jobs. So you will not load all the effort on the web-server (IIS) and the application will not lost the jobs in case of the web-server restart or the web-application restarts.

To create this solution, you will have 3 points to think about.

**Queue design and management**

Sure you can use one of the Queuing servers (e.g. MSMQ, ActiveMQ, ZeroQ). But I recommend to use a new table on your database as a queue for simplicity. Find in the following link how to use database table as a queue.
http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

**Job Scheduling**

You have two options here Windows Task Scheduler and QuatrZ.NET. I recommend to use QuatrZ.Net for this part as it is more customizable and can fit for all your needs.

**Hosting Service**

You can use QuartZ.NET server deployment or you can build your own hosting service using [.NET 4 Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) and based on QuartZ IJob contract and its [Corn expressions](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html).

Comment: +1 for suggesting a queue-based asynchronous solution, -1 for recommending a db as a queue :-). Use the right tool for the job (e.g. look at NServiceBus)